# Up and Downtime Constraints - An Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am working on a project and have run into a roadblock, any help will be greatly appreciated:

We are trying to minimize cost of running a series of generators.  Each generator has a unique cost of generation for generating power, and a fixed cost (which is only taken into account if the generator is on), and we have to meet demand for different time periods.

The additional constraint, which I have been stuck on for a very long time now, is that the generators have different up and downtime constraints.

We have two cases to solve: 1) five generators and four time periods, and 2) 8 generators and 12 time periods.

In case 1) the generators have an uptime of 2 periods and downtime of 2 periods.  In case 2) the generators have an uptime of 3 periods and a downtime of 2 periods.

NOTE: any generator could be off the entire time or on the entire time, but if it were to change from on to off, or off to on, the minimum up/downtime would have to be respected.

We are required to come up with one LP to solve both cases.  I am looking for some help with creating a constraint (or constraints?) to ensure that up and downtime is respected.  So I'm assuming it must be data independent... (otherwise how could we solve both cases with one model?)  It's supposed to be MILP, and use binary variables.

I was thinking to use a big M constraint, but I am unsure on how to do so...

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.  We are writing in AMPL if that helps in any way...(must be linear)